# Дореволюционная орфография

Tags: орфография, старая-грамматика

Может, мой вопрос достаточно глупый, но всегда занимало вот что. В старой орфографии было окончание "-iя" - "Московскiя вљдомости" (не знаю, удалось ли правильно написать). Сейчас бы написали "МосковскИЕ ведомости". Так вот, это окончание "-iя" было только на письме или говорили тоже так? А если да, то почему после революции (видимо, согласно реформе Луначарского) стали говорить иначе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написание -iя.-ыя в прилагательных женского рода (и еще в нескольких подобных случаях)  отражало грамматику и, соответственно, произношение XVII-XVIII веков. К XIX веку фонетические различия между прилагательными мужского и женского рода исчезли. Это и дало основания для орфографического закрепления. С ним отпала необходимость и для грамматического различения родов множественного числа.

Только не списывайте все на Луначарского. У истоков реформы стояли выдающиеся русские лингвисты начала XX века: Шахматов, Фортунатов, Бодуэн де Куртенэ и другие. Реформа готовилась с 1904 г. и начало её планировалась на 1914-1915, но помешала Первая мировая война. Тем не менее уже первое Временное правительство (Князь Львов) одобрило "мягкий" вариант реформы, но тоже не смогло провести его в жизнь. Большевики просто воспользовались ситуацией и провели реформу силовым методом. К сожалению, многие деятели эмиграции (Бунин, например) отвергли реформу именно по причине её ошибочного ассоциирования исключительно с новой властью.