# Как эффективнее усвоить дореформенную орфографию

Tags: орфография, устаревшие-слова, др.-русский

Кто-нибудь знает какие-нибудь тексты, ориентированные на изучение особенностей дореформенной грамматики? Я имею в виду чёткое перечисление того, какие именно правила были изменены, и как быстро научиться "правильно" писать по дореформенным правилам.

По теме я тут нашёл два вопроса, [Дореформенная грамматика](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/21873/178672) и [Дореволюционная орфография](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/4140/178672), но там никаких ссылок нет.

**Позже** -

по совету [Tagirix](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/3739/tagirix) заглянул в Википедию, там по ссылке на [Сборник ресурсов по старой орфографии в сети](http://arhivarij.narod.ru/do_revoliucii.html) в частности имеется

[Краткое пособіе по старой орѳографіи русскаго языка](http://arhivarij.narod.ru/asmus_s_sajta_slovnik.rusgor.ru_zerkalo_slovnik.narod.ru.pdf) протоиерея Валентина Асмуса,

[Введеніе въ дореформенную орѳографію](http://slovnik.narod.ru/old/pravila/01.html) С. Виницкого,

[Правила дореволюціонной орѳографіи](http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/index1.html) из «Записной книжки для учащихся» на 1909-1910 гг,

[Правила русскаго правописанiя](http://slovnik.narod.ru/reprint/pravila.htm)

[Буква Ѣ. Руководство къ употребленію этой буквы въ письмѣ](http://arhivarij.narod.ru/do_revoliucii/Bukva_jatj_s_sajta_rsl-ru.pdf) А. Баласо́гло,

[Словарь дореволюціонной орѳографіи съ удареніями](http://www.dorev.ru/),

оказавшиеся чрезвычайно полезными для меня.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вас это так сильно интересует, в сети можно найти информацию. Та же Википедия, допустим, имеет [страницу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F) на эту тему. Вот это еще есть полезная [информация](http://russian7.ru/2014/01/7-tajn-reformy-russkogo-yazyka-1918-goda/). А вообще, я думаю, нужно всё из печатных книг черпать.

Comment: Спасибо большое, да, я должен был в первую очередь заглянуть в Википедию. Тамошняя ссылка на [Сборник ресурсов по старой орфографии в сети](http://arhivarij.narod.ru/do_revoliucii.html) содержит много полезного для меня, например [Краткое пособіе по старой орѳографіи русскаго языка](http://arhivarij.narod.ru/asmus_s_sajta_slovnik.rusgor.ru_zerkalo_slovnik.narod.ru.pdf) и многое другое. На той же страничке Википедии упоминается книга П. И. Давыдова "Справочник по старой орфографии русского языка". (М.: б. и., 2013, 349 с., ISBN 978-5-8493-0218-8). Вы бы не могли добавить всё это в свой ответ?

Comment: Лучше добавьте это в свой вопрос. Я честно говоря, не очень понимаю, что там такого страшного в старой орфографии, что её надо углубленно изучать на отдельных текстах. Там два десятка правил (это если разбить на совсем мелкие), из которых только правила употребления ятя вызывают некоторые трудности.

Comment: @IrinaGL пожалуй, так и сделаю, хотя лучше бы было эту информацию иметь в качестве ответа. Ну а правила эти ведь надо где-нибудь найти, правда? Желательно в сети. Я, собственно, об этом и спросил, где их найти, сколько бы их ни было.

Comment: (Я бы, например, сам догадался, как раньше писалось слово "орфография"? Исключено!)

Comment: Орфография - это мелочь. Фита встречается только в десятке греческих слов, запомнить несложно.  Да и там часто писали через ферт то, что положено через фиту. Это не было большим грехом.

Comment: А какова цель вашего изучения? Фактически столь продвинутый уровень нужен только единичным специалистам по расшифровке и стилизации текстов.

Comment: @IrinaGL Вы уж извините, но я только сейчас случайно заметил, что, оказывается, оставил Ваш вопрос без ответа. Видите ли, мне всегда не хватает выразительных средств, я считаю - чем больше нюансов-тонкостей в языке, тем больше возможностей передавать разные смыслы, ощущения и т. п. В Грузинском похожую реформу провёл Илья Чавчавадзе, удалив пять букв и упростив некоторые аспекты грамматики. Не думаю, что это был шаг в положительном направлении. Например, отсутствие йоты (ჲ) вызвало целый ряд неуклюжих транскрипций, которые, уверен, просто-напросто уродуют язык.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам будет интересна лекция В. А. Плунгяна, в которой он рассказывает о некоторых важных нюансах, связанных с правилами дореформенной орфографии, и их истоках. К сожалению, это сокращенная версия соответствующего курса, специально сделанная для Грамоты.ру, но все же, по-моему, она представляет большой интерес.

https://youtu.be/HNFbK6gIe04